# leaflet gradient alert marker

Tags: leaflet, gradient, heatmap

I'm looking for heatmap for markers. I have a range from 0-100 for gradient color from blue to red. I want to show the color based on value of blue and red. How can I achieve it. Below is the image of map I'm expecting.

[image]

Comment: I don't see gradient in your pic. Why not add a L.circle under the Marker and give it the color it has to be according to the "gradient" ?

Comment: Its a photoshop image, I'm panning to show a gradient color under markers. I will give try with L.cricle.